# Incompatible Objective-C types - trying to pass NSURL

Tags: ios, memory-management, webview, nsurl

I have this line of code, where I'm trying to assign a URL from an annotation on a custom MKAnnotation to a UIWebView controller.

```
webViewController.webViewURL = annotation.url;
```

Basically, I have an NSURL stored in annotation.url, and am trying to send this NSURL to webViewController.webViewURL.

When I try running this code, I get "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" in the console. Running the Allocations Instrument (with NSZombiesEnabled) didn't show any zombies... I can't understand why this is happening, especially since, if I change the line to use 'URLWithString...' and build a new NSURL...

```
webViewController.webViewURL = [NSURL URLWithString:annotation.url];
```

...it works without a problem, though I get the warning: `Incompatible Objective-C types 'struct NSURL *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'URLWithString:' from distinct Objective-C type`

Comment: Can you also post how the webViewURL property is configured and how and where is it released?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up simply passing an NSString via the annotation.url, and converting that string to an NSURL in the method I was using above.

Oh well.